# Blocked a frame from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.paypal.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. What does this mean?

Tags: javascript, paypal

I have a website that I am using the PayPal smart buttons in. When testing it in the Sandbox environment it worked perfectly but when I changed the Client ID from the Sandbox one to the Live Client ID, the Payments will not go through.

The PayPal buttons still render and it still takes you to the checkout window and still allows you to Pay, but when you click the payment button, the window closes and the buyer gets an email saying that PayPal found some risks associated with the payment? Click the PayPal buttons, in the JavaScript console log I get this error 3 times:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.mobilemastersshop.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.paypal.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

Is this why it won't work and if so how do I fix it? I am using an SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt so the URL is secure but do I need to change anything in the .htaccess file for PayPal to work?

### After Comments

I think the issue is that is didn't this section:

[image]

But I do not know where to include these vars. My PayPal button render code is:

```js
<script>
        paypal.Buttons({
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
                return actions.order.create({
                    "purchase_units": [{
                        "amount": {
                            "value": applyDiscount(),
                            "currency_code": "USD",
                            "breakdown": {
                                "item_total": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": applyDiscount()
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        "items": PayPalItems()
                    }
                    ]
                });
            },
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
                    alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
                    window.location.href = "orderConfirmed.php";
                    clearCart()
                });
            }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
        //This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
    </script>
```

I guessed that the vars have to go in this script so my Live Client ID script looks like this:

```html
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AU25a1zm8IuMS_HHl-90AUaHjQBdA-TnzsaSkF2do60t7VS8IukeuBhUY552W1pY_CE0QIY2h9i5p1cK">
    // Add your client ID and secret
    let PAYPAL_CLIENT = 'AU25a1zm8IuMS_HHl-90AUaHjQBdA-TnzsaSkF2do60t7VS8IukeuBhUY552W1pY_CE0QIY2h9i5p1cK';
    let PAYPAL_SECRET = 'EIwsaGfAw7tiNBJBBb7jVWxrH6fqSLJ0fg-oNAJ-pQc37nM0ndSwqN6L0tRIvrNv9y5l2rXJdw914NUE';

    // Point your server to the PayPal API
    let PAYPAL_ORDER_API = 'https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/';
</script>
```

Comment: I cannot guess what is wrong without testing it, and https://www.mobilemastersshop.com does not display anything

Comment: I will upload files now

Comment: Well I didn't see anything about the error you reference. When testing with a live account that declines, the console error is "Error: Order could not be captured", and there is no message to the user, so that is something you also need to improve.

Comment: I am no seeing this error you are referring to, I will update this question to give more info

Comment: @PrestonPHX I have made the edits

Comment: Cannot GET /smart/smart-payment-buttons.min.js.map <- this is the issue after i made those changes to the code

Comment: Normal message, not an issue

Comment: Exposed credentials for a Payment provider?? I very hope that you changed them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AU25a1zm8IuMS_HHl-90AUaHjQBdA-TnzsaSkF2do60t7VS8IukeuBhUY552W1pY_CE0QIY2h9i5p1cK">
    // Add your client ID and secret
    let PAYPAL_CLIENT = 'AU25a1zm8IuMS_HHl-90AUaHjQBdA-TnzsaSkF2do60t7VS8IukeuBhUY552W1pY_CE0QIY2h9i5p1cK';
    let PAYPAL_SECRET = 'EIwsaGfAw...redacted';

    // Point your server to the PayPal API
    let PAYPAL_ORDER_API = 'https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/';
</script>
```

A client-side integration only uses a client-id, which is on the first script line.  All the other information you added in is for a server-side integration, is not used here, and so is not needed.